# Mapcache + SQLite

Tags: mapserver, sqlite, mapcache

i tried to configure mapcache to use with sqlite database, but i have some problems. I want make cache for four layers, but i dont know, how to do this. When i make more tilesets, i get error: duplicate tileset with name "mirror"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapcache mode="split_mirror" >

<cache name="sqlite" type="sqlite3">
    <dbfile>/opt/share/maps/mapcache_data/test/test.db</dbfile>
    <pragma name="max_page_count">10000000</pragma>
    <detect_blank/>
</cache>

<cache name="sqlite2" type="sqlite3">
    <dbfile>/opt/share/maps/mapcache_data/test/test2.db</dbfile>
    <pragma name="max_page_count">10000000</pragma>
    <detect_blank/>
</cache>

<source name="zdroj" type="wms">
    <getmap>
        <params> 
         <MAP>/opt/share/maps/map_configs/czechia/main.map</MAP>
          <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
            <transparent>true</transparent>
            <compression>fast</compression>
            <colors>256</colors>
        </params>
    </getmap>
    <http>
        <url>http://172.17.0.1:8085/fcgi-bin/mapserv?</url>
    </http>
</source>

<format name="PNG_BEST" type ="PNG">
    <transparent>true</transparent>
    <compression>fast</compression>
     <colors>256</colors>
</format>

<tileset name="layer1">
    <source>zdroj</source> 
    <cache>sqlite</cache>
    <grid>gridRP</grid>
    <format>PNG_BEST</format>
    <metatile>5 5</metatile> 
    <metabuffer>125</metabuffer>
    <expires>1000</expires>
 </tileset>

<tileset name="layer2">
    <source>zdroj</source> 
    <cache>sqlite2</cache>
    <grid>gridRP</grid>
    <format>PNG_BEST</format>
    <metatile>5 5</metatile> 
    <metabuffer>125</metabuffer>
    <expires>1000</expires>
 </tileset>

<grid name="gridRP">         
   <!-- <extent>0 5000000 4000000 8000000 </extent>-->
    <extent>1326946 6055035 2520587 6633511 </extent>
    <srs>EPSG:3857</srs>
    <units>m</units>
    <size>256 256</size>
    <resolutions>156412 78206 39103 19551 9776 4888 2444 1222 610.984 305.492 152.746 76.373 38.187 19.093 9.547 4.773 2.387 1.193 0.596 0.298</resolutions>
</grid>

<service type="wms" enabled="true">
    <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
    <format>PNG_BEST</format>
</service>
<service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
<service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
<service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
<service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
<service type="ve" enabled="true"/>

<errors>report</errors>
<lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>

</mapcache>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMS parameters require LAYERS, as ***< LAYERS >layer1,layer2< /LAYERS >***. Thus, to create a cache for each layer you must create a source with each of the layers, and associate each cache, respectively.

```
<cache name="sqlite" type="sqlite3">
    <dbfile>/opt/share/maps/mapcache_data/test/test.db</dbfile>
    <pragma name="max_page_count">10000000</pragma>
    <detect_blank/>
</cache>

<cache name="sqlite2" type="sqlite3">
    <dbfile>/opt/share/maps/mapcache_data/test/test2.db</dbfile>
    <pragma name="max_page_count">10000000</pragma>
    <detect_blank/>
</cache>

<source name="zdroj_layer1" type="wms">
    <getmap>
        <params> 
         <MAP>/opt/share/maps/map_configs/czechia/main.map</MAP>
          <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
          <LAYERS>layer1</LAYERS>
            <transparent>true</transparent>
            <compression>fast</compression>
            <colors>256</colors>
        </params>
    </getmap>
    <http>
        <url>http://172.17.0.1:8085/fcgi-bin/mapserv?</url>
    </http>
</source>

<source name="zdroj_layer2" type="wms">
    <getmap>
        <params> 
         <MAP>/opt/share/maps/map_configs/czechia/main.map</MAP>
          <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
          <LAYERS>layer2</LAYERS>
            <transparent>true</transparent>
            <compression>fast</compression>
            <colors>256</colors>
        </params>
    </getmap>
    <http>
        <url>http://172.17.0.1:8085/fcgi-bin/mapserv?</url>
    </http>
</source>

<format name="PNG_BEST" type ="PNG">
    <transparent>true</transparent>
    <compression>fast</compression>
     <colors>256</colors>
</format>

<tileset name="layer1">
    <source>zdroj_layer1</source> 
    <cache>sqlite</cache>
    <grid>gridRP</grid>
    <format>PNG_BEST</format>
    <metatile>5 5</metatile> 
    <metabuffer>125</metabuffer>
    <expires>1000</expires>
 </tileset>

<tileset name="layer2">
    <source>zdroj_layer2</source>  
    <cache>sqlite2</cache>
    <grid>gridRP</grid>
    <format>PNG_BEST</format>
    <metatile>5 5</metatile> 
    <metabuffer>125</metabuffer>
    <expires>1000</expires>
 </tileset>
```